# How do I diagnose suspected power issues?

Tags: pi-3, rpi.gpio

I have a Pi 3 project that has quite a few things attached.

- 4 DHT-22s powered from the 5v rail (5m cable length, so I needed the 5v for the voltage loss).
  Wired in like this
  [image]
- 2 Magnetic door reed contacts wired in like this

[image]

This all works. However I wanted to add 2 relays. One of those twin relay boards that take 
5v & GND plus GPIO poins. When I do this, the DHT sensors or the reed contacts stop working randomly.

I am suspecting I am reaching a voltage issue / power issue with the Pi. The power supply is 2.5a.

How do I start resolving this issue with the power?

Comment: "DHT-22s powered from the 5v rail (5m cable length, so I needed the 5v for the voltage loss"  - total rubbish I don't care why or how but connecting 5V to a GPIO risks damaging the Pi.

Comment: IMHO, you could get a good answer if you used a schematic instead of these diagrams. Here's how to use the [schematic tool](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2074/83790).

Comment: Both comments noted. I will action both today.

Answer (score 1):

At the command line prompt type dmesg.  The log will tell you if you are having power problems.

Comment: I don't think the SoC necessarily experiences undervoltage (BTW you can `dmesg | grep "Under-voltage"` or `grep "Under-voltage" /var/log/syslog`) just because something on the GPIOs isn't getting enough juice, although it may.